# How to fix error "xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default" on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu

When I type `xrandr` on my Lenovo Laptop with Ubuntu 14.04 I get the following output:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1600 x 900, current 1600 x 900, maximum 1600 x 900
default connected primary 1600x900+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1600x900       77.0*
```

How to fix the error `Failed to get size of gamma for output default`? Is this an error in the first place? Should I worry about it at all?

Comment: It may be a driver issue.

Comment: And how can I find out? How can I update the driver?

Comment: You could have a look in the system logs and see if there's any indication there.  The driver's part of the kernel; I would not bother trying to update it until you are 1) sure that's the issue (I'm just casually guessing), 2) sure that it's been fixed.  That could take some googling -- but if there aren't any further consequences and this is a fairly new or rare model display adapter, it might not have been reported by anyone.

Comment: AFAIK the drriver is up to date and working correctly. I am not able to install something extra. However, what does this error message mean? Is it something to worry about? Do I need to fix it? I am trying to display the screen of my laptop on a monitor (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176423/hdmi-connection-not-recognized-on-laptop-with-ubuntu-14-04) but without any success.

Comment: Ubuntu have called it [a bug on xrandr](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/x11-utils/+bug/1078695) although it hasn't been acted on.  However, based on your other question about the external monitor, I'd say there has to be some kind of driver (or hardware) problem if you are getting only one output -- that's unlikely to be xrandr's fault, since the kernel manages the hardware.

Comment: So everyone running Ubuntu 14.04 has the same problem and is unable to connect an external monitor via HDMI? I cannot believe this is true. I also can exclude a hardware problem since the laptop shows the screen content on an external monitor when rebooting the laptop with Windows (and without touching any cables).

Comment: No, it's probably not Ubuntu specific and it is not everyone -- it's just a few based on the specific hardware they are using, which is why it can go uncorrected for a long time.